# Sum like operation for strings in t-sql

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000

I already have query to concatenate

```
DECLARE @ids VARCHAR(8000) 
SELECT @ids = COALESCE(@ids + ', ', '') + concatenatedid
FROM #HH
```

but if I have to do it inline how can I do that? Any help please.

```
SELECT sum(quantity), COALESCE(@ids + ', ', '') + concatenatedid from #HH
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the XML PATH trick. You may need a CAST

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(
    (
    SELECT
        ',' + concatenatedid
    FROM
        #HH
    FOR XML PATH ('')
    )
    , 2, 7999)
```

Also:

- [Join characters using SET BASED APPROACH (Sql Server 2005)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513610/join-characters-using-set-based-approach-sql-server-2005/1513728#1513728)
- [Subquery returned more than 1 value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115797/subquery-returned-more-than-1-value/6115978#6115978)

Comment: Thanks gbn, what is myTable is it #HH? I have only one table #HH.